# Taking Thread dump/ Heap dump of Azure Kubernetes pods

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, heap-dump, thread-dump

We are running our kafka stream application on Azure kubernetes written in java. We are new to kubernetes. To debug an issue we want to take thread dump of the running pod.

Below are the steps we are following to take the dump.

1. Building our application with below docker file.

   ```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/java/jdk:11-zulu-alpine
   RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache gcompat
   RUN addgroup -S user1 && adduser -S user1 -G user1
   USER user1
   WORKDIR .
   COPY target/my-application-1.0.0.0.jar .
   ```
2. Submitting the image with below deployment yaml file

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
name: my-application-v1.0.0.0
spec:
replicas: 1
selector:
matchLabels:
name: my-application-pod
app: my-application-app
template:
metadata:
name: my-application-pod
labels:
name: my-application-pod
app: my-application-app
spec:
nodeSelector:
agentpool: agentpool1
containers:
- name: my-application-0
image: myregistry.azurecr.io/my-application:v1.0.0.0
imagePullPolicy: Always
command: ["java","-jar","my-application-1.0.0.0.jar","input1","$(connection_string)"]
env:
- name: connection_string
valueFrom:
configMapKeyRef:
name: my-application-configmap
key: connectionString
resources:
limits:
cpu: "4"
requests:
cpu: "0.5"

3. To get a shell to a Running container you can run the command below:

   kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> -- sh
4. To get thread dump running below command

   jstack PID > threadDump.tdump

but getting permission denied error
[image]

Can some one suggest how to solve this or steps to take thread/heap dumps.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Seems like you do not have the permission to create the file in this directory. You might try to create it in the /tmp directory? `jstack 1 > /tmp/threadDump.tdump` .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you likely need the thread dump locally, you can bypass creating the file in the pod and just stream it directly to a file on your local computer:

```
kubectl exec -i POD_NAME -- jstack 1 > threadDump.tdump
```

If your thread dumps are large you may want to consider piping to `pv` first to get a nice progress bar.

Comment: Similarly i want to take heap dump. I tried below command kubectl exec -i <POD_NAME> -- jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=application_heap_dump.bin 1.. But it is not working can you please suggest

Comment: I don't know the jmap tool. Maybe you can specify `-` or `/dev/stdout` as filename? Or just drop the `file=` part?